# Voltage on LM4140 Vout

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-reference

I'm using an LDO called [LM4140](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4140.pdf) with an op amp, where VREF is connected to the output of an Op-amp via a resistor network. As the op-amp will be outputting voltages from -10v to 10v, is there any chance of the LM4140 being damaged, should it have an "opposing" voltage (e.g. when op-amp output is 10v) on the VREF pin?

Being a high precision voltage reference which appears to lend itself well to such applications, I would think that it would be protected in these scenarios. Can anyone direct me to somewhere in the datasheet, where I might find the answers I'm looking for (don't really know what I'm looking for)?

VREF below is the LM4140 output.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a schematic so we know what your "resistor network" looks like?

Comment: Circuit diagram appears to be lacking.

Comment: Diagram added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 'In-' voltage can exceed Vref then you should add some additional load to soak up the current through R4 unless there is such a load somewhere else in your circuit.

The LM4040 cannot sink current beyond a few uA and it's better to keep it sourcing a bit of current rather than hovering near zero at times. See this figure from the  [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4140.pdf).

[image]

If the op-amp output voltage can be 10V maximum (use the maximum voltage that could be present) then there could be current

Is = (10-Vref)/(R4+R5+R9) flowing so you should add a resistor to ground from the LM4040 output of Rx = Vref/Is or preferably a bit less than that.

You don't mention the value of Vref but the LM4040 only goes up to 4.096V so with a 10V output it will definitely be required.

P.S. Maybe R9 should be marked 1.8K.

Comment: Where would you place this load? And what kind of load would you choose?

Comment: From Vref to ground. Just a resistor is fine. I showed you above how to calculate the value.

Comment: I see that the resistor from Vref to GND keeps the LM4140 sourcing current, but how does this prevent it from receiving current?

Comment: If you want Vref to stay in spec all you have to do is make sure the LM4140 is always sourcing current. So the sum of the current to the load and from (or to) the op-amp must be greater than zero, preferably a bit higher. I would make it 50 or 100uA minimum (sourcing). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Just to check I've calculated this correctly, with a vref of 2.048, we're talking about adding a resistor around 14kohms?

Comment: @19172281 More like 10K would be a bit better, I think. 14K would be just okay.